# Access ref elements inside a repeat.for

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I've got a `ref` of an object inside a `repeat.for` which looks like this

```
<tr repeat.for="machine of machines">
    <div with.bind="machine" ref="pb">...</div>
</tr>
```

Aurelia Inspector shows the ref under the machine object:

[image]

I tried to access it in `attached()` like this:

```
attached() {
    console.log(this.machines[0].pb)
}
```

but of course this will return an error since `pb` does not exist on the object.

Usually when I try to access ref-bound elements in my Typescript code, I know I need to initialize them first. But how can I do that now since it's inside of another object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. Defined the objects in typescript as

```
pbElements = [];
```

And set this in the html:

```
<tr repeat.for="machine of machines">
    <div ref="pbElements[$index]">...</div>
</tr>
```